# How to position images on dropped area using nth child in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `four images` inside `class` `box` having `id` `box1`, `box2`, `box3` and `box4`..

`each image` can be `dragged and dropped` to `rectangle` below..

**my problem** is when i `try to position` it on the `dropped area` using `nth child` in `css` `it is not working`

where is the mistake happenining in css?

How to position images on dropped area using nth child..

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  console.log(data);
    $("#"+data).css("position","unset");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
body{

background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
   background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28.3vh;
  left: -10.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13.7vh;
  left: -10.98vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box2 p {
 width: 5.0vw;
  height: 5.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.7vh;
  left: 43.98vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  
}

#box3 p {
  width: 7.0vw;
  height: 7.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28.3vh;
  left: 40.98vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box4 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.boxright1 p {
  font-size: calc(2vw);
  height: 4vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;

  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
 color: #0066ff;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #999, 0px 0px 0px #888, 0px 0px 0px #777, 0px 0px 0px #6066, 0px 2px 0px #555, 0px 0px 0px #444, 0px 0px 0px #333, 0px 0
 px 0px #001135;
 font:'ChunkFiveRegular';

}

.boxright1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.3vh;
  left: 17.5vw;
  
  width: 61.0vw;
  height: 35.0vh;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid black;

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image:url(images/name%20board%20witout%20rope2.png);
  background-size: 40vw 55vh; 
  }
.boxright1 .box{
    position: absolute;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 155px;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(2) {
    top: 5px;
    left:215px;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(3) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 315px;

}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(4) {
    top: 5px;
    left: 415px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>applying nth child to Class boxright1 not working</p>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
      
        <div class="box" id="box1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300)">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="box" id="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/g/200/300)">
          <p name="values" id="name2" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="box" id="box3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0)">
          <p name="values" id="name3" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="box" id="box4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300/?gravity=east)">
          <p name="values" id="name4" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="boxright1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="4" name="d"></div>
```

Comment: curious mixture of JavaScript and jQuery in your JavaScript...

Comment: @yvonne-aburrow trying to simplify and achieve the desired functinality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically your error is that you forgot the `.` in your css to select a class

so instead of (selecting element `<box>`)

```
.boxright1 box:nth-child(1) {
```

it should be (selecting `class="box"`)

```
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(1) {
```

And add !important to your nth-child top and left values to make it override the initial #box_x values

But generally you should use some more elegant approach like a (flex)grid or sth

Comment: Would also have to re-arrange the styles a bit, as the ids (`#box1` etc) will have higher priority, so the positioning using nth-child wouldn't apply.

Comment: @Jupiter I know, because the styles are overridden by the id selectors. Is the code you posted the complete example or have you taken it out of an existing page? The CSS really need to be re-worked for this to work. Would you be able to use it if the entire code was restructured?

Comment: @jle  i want the image to get arraged as i mentioned for each (say for child elements) how to solve this?

Comment: @jle css rearranging is ok to avoid overriden by id...i can use it its ok..

Comment: @jle the code is complete..... have some other features working on above it but does not have direct control to it....  it is ok if you rearrange the css...

Comment: just add `!important` to your nth-child top and left values to make it overrides. But generally you should use some more elegant approach like a (flex)grid  or sth. ...

Answer (score 1):

Already you set `#box1` as `absolute` position. so inside `.boxright1` dropped area `nth-child` not working. so you can change

```
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

change into

```
#container .box:nth-child(1) { 
  position: absolute;
  ....
  ....
}
```

Now you try to position on the `dropped area` using `nth child`

```
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

### **[View Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/QzrZgd?editors=1100)**

```
body{

background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
   background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
#container .box:nth-child(1) { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3vh;
  left: -10.8vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


#container .box:nth-child(2) {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 13.7vh;
  left: -10.98vw;

  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box2 p {
 width: 5.0vw;
  height: 5.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#container .box:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.7vh;
  left: 43.98vw;

  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;


}

#box3 p {
  width: 7.0vw;
  height: 7.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#container .box:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28.3vh;
  left: 40.98vw;

  cursor:pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box4 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.boxright1 p {
  font-size: calc(2vw);
  height: 4vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;

  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

    color: #0066ff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #999, 0px 0px 0px #888, 0px 0px 0px #777, 0px 0px 0px #6066, 0px 2px 0px #555, 0px 0px 0px #444, 0px 0px 0px #333, 0px 0
    px 0px #001135;
    font:'ChunkFiveRegular';

}

.boxright1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.3vh;
  left: 17.5vw;

  width: 61.0vw;
  height: 35.0vh;

  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid black;

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image:url(images/name%20board%20witout%20rope2.png);
  background-size: 40vw 55vh; 
  }
.boxright1 .box{
    position: absolute !important;
  background-size: contain;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(2) {
    top: 5px;
    left:140px;
}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(3) {
    top: 125px;
    left: 50px;

}
.boxright1 .box:nth-child(4) {
    top: 145px;
    left: 145px;
}
```

Comment: when one image is dropped in the rectangle...there is re arrangement of position of original three images....which is not permissible

Comment: thanks for the pen....how to remove the original images rearrangement when  one image get dropped

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at the elements inspector inside the `.boxright1` drop container, I saw that there were inlined styles on the `.box` elements.

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
    position: unset;
}
```

It looks like you're unsetting the values in the JS on the elements after you drop them.

```
$("#"+data).css("position","unset");
```

Because `position` is getting `unset`, the `top` and `left` values have no meaning anymore.

If you could remove that `position: unset` from happening, then the elements would respect the `top` and `left` properties you set, and get positioned relative to the drop container.